# Is "but rather" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Is the use of "but rather" correct here?

> The United States' decision to drop atomic bombs on Hiroshima and Nagasaki was not a diplomatic measure to intimidate the Soviet Union, **but rather** a military measure designed to force Japan’s unconditional surrender.

Comment: Yes. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: _rather_ means _on the contrary_.

Comment: Yes, it's correct, although it becomes rather a false contrast if you champion the view that the bombs were dropped in order to force unconditional surrender _before_ the Soviet Union, which had entered the war a few days previously, could gain much Japanese territory.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is. The *but* is necessary because the second part of the sentence is not a clause--it doesn't stand alone as a proposition. The *rather* itself approaches redundancy, but it does intensify contrast. In order to lose the *but*, the sentence needs to do something like this:

...not a diplomatic measure to intimidate the Soviet Union; rather, *it was* a military measure...

It might help to imagine a clunky pair of commas before and after the *rather*. Note nevertheless how little is lost by dropping the *rather* altogether.